# copy and append a tag multiple times using xml.etree.ElementTree Python

Tags: python, elementtree

Sample Input xml:

```
<Document>
 <tagap>
   <taga>
     <taga1>vala1</taga1>
     <taga2>vala2</taga2>
   </taga>
 </tagap>
  <tagb>
    <tagb1>valb1</tagb1>
    <tagb2>valb2</tagb2>
  </tagb>
 </Document>
```

one tag "taga" needs to be appended multiple times. Following python code works, but the closing of first occurrence is misplaced.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import copy
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root=tree.getroot()
print (root.tag)

node=root.find('taga')
taga2 = copy.copy(node)
print(taga2.tag)
node.append(taga2)
node.append(taga2)
node.append(taga2)
tree.write("out_test.xml")
```

Following is the output: see the first taga termination was not done properly.

```
<Document>
  <taga>
    <taga1>vala1</taga1>
    <taga2>vala2</taga2>
  <taga>
    <taga1>vala1</taga1>
    <taga2>vala2</taga2>
  </taga>
  <taga>
    <taga1>vala1</taga1>
    <taga2>vala2</taga2>
  </taga>
  <taga>
    <taga1>vala1</taga1>
    <taga2>vala2</taga2>
  </taga>
  </taga>
  <tagb>
    <tagb1>valb1</tagb1>
    <tagb2>valb2</tagb2>
  </tagb>
 </Document>
```

Comment: Don't you mean `root.append(taga2)`?

Comment: In the given example, root is parent of taga. But this need not be the case, say taga is enclosed within tagap, and if i appned to node_tagap , it could be a similar issue.

Comment: @CristiFati thanks. root.append(taga2) would work (consider tagap is the parent of taga) . But the output is reformatted with several occurrence of tagap. It could be the same sematic meaning.

Comment: The question is confusing. Please show us the exact expected output. `root.find('taga')` does not work since the root element doesn't have any *direct child* named `taga`.

Comment: @mzjn sorry for the confusion. I need to change the input. I will try to edit accordingly. Can you the solution and propose another without using iter. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import copy
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root=tree.getroot()
print (root.tag)
for tagap in root.iter('tagap'):
  for taga in tagap:
     print(taga.tag,taga.text)
     

#taga2 = copy.deepcopy(taga)
tagap.append(taga)
tagap.append(taga)
tagap.append(taga)
tree.write("out_test.xml")
```

In this case, input has only single occurrence of tagap and taga. So follwoing implemention worked. I would like to see any other solutions without using iterator.
Output:

```
<Document>
  <tagap>   
  <taga>
    <taga1>vala1</taga1>
    <taga2>vala2</taga2>
  </taga>
  <taga>
    <taga1>vala1</taga1>
    <taga2>vala2</taga2>
  </taga>
  <taga>
    <taga1>vala1</taga1>
    <taga2>vala2</taga2>
  </taga>
  <taga>
    <taga1>vala1</taga1>
    <taga2>vala2</taga2>
  </taga>
  </tagap>
  <tagb>
    <tagb1>valb1</tagb1>
    <tagb2>valb2</tagb2>
  </tagb>
 </Document>
```